# How to reset if Null? XML Linq

Tags: xml, silverlight, linq, windows-phone-7

I curently have the below which displasy a messagebox.show if the results is null. But it still gives me an unhandled exception.

How can I stop the exception and just let the user enter a different value?

```
void Trademe_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
                return;
            if (e.Error == null)


                MessageBox.Show("Wrong try Again");

            var r = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
```

Full code for clarity *******************************

```
namespace TradeMe
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient Trademe = new WebClient();
            Trademe.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Trademe_DownloadStringCompleted);
            Trademe.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Search/General.xml?search_string=" + TradeSearch.Text));

            progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = true;
            progressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;


        }



        void Trademe_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
                return;






            var r = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
            if (e.Result == null)
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong try Again");


            // Declare the namespace
            XNamespace ns = "http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1";
            listBox1.ItemsSource = from TM in r.Root.Descendants(ns + "Listing").Take(50)
                                   select new TradeItem
                                   {
                                       ImageSource = TM.Element(ns + "PictureHref").Value,
                                       Title = TM.Element(ns + "Title").Value,
                                       Region = TM.Element(ns + "Region").Value,
                                       PriceDisplay = TM.Element(ns + "PriceDisplay").Value,
                                       ListingId = TM.Element(ns + "ListingId").Value,
                                   };

           ;

            progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = false;
            progressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }



        public class TradeItem
        {
            public string Region { get; set; }
            public string ListingId { get; set; }
            public string PriceDisplay { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string ImageSource { get; set; }
        }

        private void hyperlinkButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TestPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        private void eventhandler(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as TradeItem;

            if (item != null)
            {
                string id = item.ListingId.ToString();
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TestPage.xaml?ListingId=" + id, UriKind.Relative));
            }


        }


    }
}
```

Full stack trace **************************

```
   at TradeMe.MainPage.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Trademe_DownloadStringCompleted>b__1(XElement TM)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectIterator>d__d`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.EnumerableCollectionView.InitializeSnapshot()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.EnumerableCollectionView..ctor(IEnumerable sourceCollection, ICollectionChangedListener collectionOwner)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.UpdateItemsSourceList(IEnumerable newItemsSource)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.ItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.set_ItemsSource(IEnumerable value)
   at TradeMe.MainPage.Trademe_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
   at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking whether `e.Error` is null, not whether `e.Result` is null... and you're also not returning after showing the message box.

(It's hard to know exactly what's going on - if you could say what exception you're getting and under what circumstances, that would be useful...)

EDIT: Okay, from the stack trace, it looks like it's in the selection part of the iterator. I strongly suspect that one of these lines is failing:

```
ImageSource = TM.Element(ns + "PictureHref").Value,
Title = TM.Element(ns + "Title").Value,
Region = TM.Element(ns + "Region").Value,
PriceDisplay = TM.Element(ns + "PriceDisplay").Value,
ListingId = TM.Element(ns + "ListingId").Value,
```

My guess is that one of the elements you're looking for is missing.

If you change it to the following code, it won't throw an exception - but any property which would previously have thrown an exception will be null. That may be what you want, but even if not it would at least potentially help you to find the problem:

```
ImageSource = (string) TM.Element(ns + "PictureHref"),
Title = (string) TM.Element(ns + "Title"),
Region = (string) TM.Element(ns + "Region"),
PriceDisplay = (string) TM.Element(ns + "PriceDisplay"),
ListingId = (string) TM.Element(ns + "ListingId"),
```

The explicit conversion from `XElement` to `string` will return null if the element is null, e.g.

```
XElement element = null;
string value = (string) element;
// value will be null; no exception is thrown
```

Comment: Unhandled exception error when a user types in certain values to search. I have updated with the full code. To make it clearer what I am doing.

Comment: @Rhys: "Unhandled exception error" still isn't very precise. Please post a full stack trace and label any relevant line numbers. For example, it could be that you're managing to parse the XML just fine, but it doesn't contain the elements you expect.

Comment: Full stack trace has been added. Thanks

Comment: Is there anyway for it to ignore Elements that it can't find? AS I think that may be the issues, because the XML elements change depending on the search value

Comment: @Rhys: Right, sounds like some elements aren't there. See my edit. And yes, the code I've given quite possibly does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I am learning something new every question, hopefully after asking a few hundred more questions I might be able answer some  :)

Comment: Hi, Just a quick related question if you have time. I am getting the same error on another page and have tried this fix, but to no avail. the differents is the structured like this `Question = (string)D.Element(ns + "Questions").Element(ns + "List").Element(ns + "Question").Element(ns + "Comment"),`  Do I put (string) in front of each element? Or is there a different solution for this?

Comment: There you're looking for a whole hierarchy. One option is to change each `Element` to `Elements` to get all the elements matching that pattern, and add `FirstOrDefault` at the end. That way you'll end up with either the first matching element or null - at which point casting to string will work appropriately.

Comment: I get an error when I try and make that change. Error 1 Cannot convert method group 'FirstOrDefault' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: @Rhys: It's a method - you need to call it. It's worth *understanding* how LINQ works rather than just doing things by rote though. Find the docs for Enumerable.FirstOrDefault().

Comment: Thanks, I think your right, I need to get an overall pciture. I will have a read. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

according the .NET 4.0 MSDN documentation you should handle the callback as follows:

```
private static void DownloadStringCallback2 (Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // If the request was not canceled and did not throw
    // an exception, display the resource.
    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        string textString = (string)e.Result;

        Console.WriteLine (textString);
    }
}
```

I presume you have to do something similar for WP7. So check if Cancelled is false and e.Error is not null. Then get the result.